# Cannot figure out why collectionViewContentSize.height is set to 0

Tags: ios, swift

I have a strange issue happening in my UICollectionView.  I have a UIViewController that determines the height of the collection view by setting the constant for an NSLayoutConstraint:

`@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!`

This constant value is set within a protocol method:

```
    func collectionViewHeightDidChange(_ height: CGFloat) {
        self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = height
    }
```

The above information is not necessarily where the issue is, as far as I can tell.  The issue is happening in the UIViewController below.  There is a method called heightChanged() that calculates the height and then calls the above protocol method which is in a separate UIViewController.

```
import UIKit

protocol POGIFSelectViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func collectionViewHeightDidChange(_ height: CGFloat)
    func didSelectGIF(_ selectedGIFURL: POGIFURLs)
}

class POGIFSelectViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: - Constants
    private enum Constants {
        static let POGIFCollectionViewCellIdentifier: String = "POGIFCollectionViewCell"
        static let verticalPadding: CGFloat = 16
        static let searchBarHeight: CGFloat = 40
        static let searchLabelHeight: CGFloat = 24
        static let activityIndicatorTopSpacing: CGFloat = 10
        static let gifLoadDuration: Double = 0.2
        static let gifStandardFPS: Double = 1/30
        static let gifMaxDuration: Double = 5.0
    }

    //MARK: - Localized Strings
    let localizedSearchGIFs = PALocalizedStringFromTable("RECOGNITION_IMAGE_SELECTION_GIF_BODY_TITLE", table: "Recognition-Osiris", comment: "Search GIFs") as String
    
    //MARK: - Properties
    var viewModel: POGIFSearchViewModel?
    var activityIndicator = MDCActivityIndicator()
    var gifLayout = PAGiphyCellLayout()
    var selectedGIF: POGIFURLs?

    //MARK: - IBOutlet
    @IBOutlet weak var GIFCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchGIFLabel: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            self.searchGIFLabel.text = self.localizedSearchGIFs
        }
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchField: POSearchField! {
        didSet {
            self.searchField.delegate = self
        }
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicatorContainer: UIView!
    
    //MARK: - Delegate
    weak var delegate: POGIFSelectViewControllerDelegate?

    //MARK: - View Lifecycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.setupActivityIndicator(activityIndicator: self.activityIndicator, activityIndicatorContainer: self.activityIndicatorContainer)
        self.viewModel = POGIFSearchViewModel(data: PAData.sharedInstance())
        if let viewModel = self.viewModel {
            viewModel.viewDelegate = self
            viewModel.viewDidBeginLoading()
        }
        
        self.gifLayout.delegate = self
        self.gifLayout.isAXPGifLayout = true;
        self.GIFCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = self.gifLayout
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // This Patch is to fix a bug where GIF contentSize was not calculated correctly on first load.
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)) {
            self.viewModel?.viewDidBeginLoading()
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.heightChanged()
    }
    
    //MARK: - Helper Methods
    func heightChanged() {
        print("**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged()")
        guard let delegate = self.delegate else { return }
        print("**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> self.GIFCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height: \(self.GIFCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height)")
        print("**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> Constants.verticalPadding * 3: \(Constants.verticalPadding * 3)")
        print("**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> Constants.searchLabelHeight: \(Constants.searchLabelHeight)")
        print("**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> Constants.searchBarHeight: \(Constants.searchBarHeight)")
        print("**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> activityIndicatorContainer.frame.size.height: \(activityIndicatorContainer.frame.size.height)")
        print("**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> Constants.activityIndicatorTopSpacing: \(Constants.activityIndicatorTopSpacing)")
        let height = self.GIFCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height + Constants.verticalPadding * 3 + Constants.searchLabelHeight + Constants.searchBarHeight + activityIndicatorContainer.frame.size.height + Constants.activityIndicatorTopSpacing
        print("**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> height is \(height) -> calling delegate.collectionViewHeightDidChange(\(height))");
        delegate.collectionViewHeightDidChange(height)
    }
    
    func reloadCollectionView() {
        self.GIFCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        self.GIFCollectionView.reloadData()
        self.GIFCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.heightChanged()
//        self.GIFCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    
    func imageAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIImage? {
        guard let previewURL = self.viewModel?.gifModel.items[indexPath.row].previewGIFURL else { return nil }
        
        var loadedImage: UIImage? = nil
        let imageManager = SDWebImageManager.shared()
        imageManager.loadImage(with: previewURL, options: .lowPriority, progress: nil) { (image: UIImage?, data: Data?, error: Error?, cacheType: SDImageCacheType, finished: Bool, imageURL: URL?) in
            loadedImage = image
        }
        return loadedImage
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScrollToBottom() {
        guard let viewModel = self.viewModel else { return }

        if viewModel.viewDidSearchMoreGIFs() {
            self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        } else {
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}

extension POGIFSelectViewController: POSearchFieldDelegate {
    func searchFieldTextChanged(text: String?) {
        guard let viewModel = self.viewModel else { return }
        viewModel.viewDidSearchGIFs(withSearchTerm: text)
    }
}

extension POGIFSelectViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Constants.POGIFCollectionViewCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! POGIFCollectionViewCell
        guard let previewURL = self.viewModel?.gifModel.items[indexPath.row].previewGIFURL else {
            return cell
        }

        var cellState: POGIFCollectionViewCell.CellState = .dimmedState
        if self.selectedGIF == nil {
            cellState = .defaultState
        } else if (self.selectedGIF?.previewGIFURL?.absoluteString == previewURL.absoluteString) {
            cellState = .selectedState
        }
        
        cell.setupUI(withState: cellState, URL: previewURL) { [weak self] () in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: Constants.gifLoadDuration) {
                guard let weakSelf = self else { return }
                weakSelf.GIFCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            }
        }

        if cell.GIFPreviewImageView.animationDuration > Constants.gifMaxDuration {
            cell.GIFPreviewImageView.animationDuration = Constants.gifMaxDuration
        }

        return cell
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let viewModel = self.viewModel else { return 0 }
        return viewModel.gifModel.items.count
    }
}

extension POGIFSelectViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let selectedGIF = self.viewModel?.gifModel.items[indexPath.row],
              let delegate = self.delegate else {
            return
        }
        self.selectedGIF = selectedGIF
        delegate.didSelectGIF(selectedGIF)
        self.reloadCollectionView()
    }
}

extension POGIFSelectViewController: POGIFSearchViewModelToViewProtocol {
    func didFetchGIFsWithSuccess() {
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.reloadCollectionView()
    }
    
    func didFetchGIFsWithError(_ error: Error!, request: PARequest!) {
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}

extension POGIFSelectViewController: PAGiphyLayoutCellDelegate {
    func heightForCell(givenWidth cellWidth: CGFloat, at indexPath: IndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
        guard let image = self.imageAtIndexPath(indexPath) else {
            return 0
        }
        if (image.size.height < 1 || image.size.width < 1 || self.activityIndicator.isAnimating) {
            return cellWidth
        }
        
        let scaleFactor = image.size.height / image.size.width
        let imageViewToHighlightedViewSpacing: CGFloat = 4  // this number comes from 2 * highlightedViewBorderWidth from POGIFCollectionViewCell
        return cellWidth * scaleFactor + imageViewToHighlightedViewSpacing
    }
    
    func heightForHeaderView() -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
}
```

The print statements I put in the heightChanged() method show something weird happening.  Initially, the UICollectionView shows up with a height of 1973:

```
self.GIFCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height: 1811.6800537109375
**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> Constants.verticalPadding * 3: 48.0
**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> Constants.searchLabelHeight: 24.0
**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> Constants.searchBarHeight: 40.0
**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> activityIndicatorContainer.frame.size.height: 40.0
**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> Constants.activityIndicatorTopSpacing: 10.0
**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> height is 1973.6800537109375 -> calling delegate.collectionViewHeightDidChange(1973.6800537109375)
**** PORecognitionImageSelectionViewController -> collectionViewHeightDidChange(_:) -> height: 1973.6800537109375
```

However, when I search for a new GIF (and I've made sure that I have new data after the search), the height of `self.GIFCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height` seems to be 0.  I can't figure out why.  This makes the UICollectionView too small (in terms of height) and you can't see the cells.

```
self.GIFCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height: 0.0
**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> Constants.verticalPadding * 3: 48.0
**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> Constants.searchLabelHeight: 24.0
**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> Constants.searchBarHeight: 40.0
**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> activityIndicatorContainer.frame.size.height: 40.0
**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> Constants.activityIndicatorTopSpacing: 10.0
**** POGIFSelectViewController -> heightChanged() -> height is 162.0 -> calling delegate.collectionViewHeightDidChange(162.0)
**** PORecognitionImageSelectionViewController -> collectionViewHeightDidChange(_:) -> height: 162.0
```

Any idea why this is happening?